# Datatabel Search (or filter?) by index and redraw

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

i know how to search for a **value** programmatically and redraw the DataTable so that it shows only rows containing the given value.
I do that like so:

`this.api().search('8000').draw();`

But now i have the need to do the same but not use a value this time, but show only the row with the given **id**.

Each row in the DataTable has an id like so:

```
<tr id="198">
  <td>8000</td><td>turnover</td>
</tr>
```

I know the index of the row with id 198 via:

`var rowIndex = this.api().row('#198');`

But how to get the DataTable to only show the row with that index?

Via Google i saw people that would place the id in a separate column and use search for that, but i think there must be a more efficient and better way as every row already has an id and i know the index of the row that i want to show.

Maybe it's simple but I googled a long time, tried lots but none of 'em worked.
Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: The [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) function will only search for data in the DataTable - and the data in `id="198"` is not part of the DataTables data set - it is only part of the HTML (DOM) data. This is why other solutions you may have seen involve adding that data to the DataTable. You don't have to make that data visible to the end user.

Comment: But there may be other considerations - I assume you want to find only an exact match for `198` - and not also other IDs such as `21983` and so on... And do you also want the global search to work as normal for all the other data in the table? Out of interest, how are these IDs generated? Are they from an external source (e.g. a database), or are they the row order of the source data in the HTML table? Or something else?

Comment: Thx for answering. the ID’s are the records ID’s from the database table. So while the rows in the datatable have an index, every table row (tr) has an rowid attribute which holds the database record id. 

i have indeed added that id as a hidden column to the datatable, but searching for 198 for instance will not only show a row that has 198 in its hidden 'id' field, but also if a row contains 198 inside any other column -> not wanted.... 

So the id-in-a-column idea isn't what im after i'm afraid. i'm still trying, but it's a long road :-(

Comment: It sounds like either a compromise is needed, or you need 2 separate search fields (one for "contains" for all visible columns - the standard global search field) and another new search field, just for ID - using an exact match, for the hidden column's data. If you have that 2nd search field, you could (probably) use a custom search which extracts the DOM data from the `<tr>` ID - no need for the hidden column.